# Only 1 thread starts when multi-threading in Python 3

Tags: python-3

`t2.start`, (the last line), does not execute until I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Why is this the case?

```
import threading
from time import sleep
def thread1():
    try:
        while True:
            print("Thread1 run")
            sleep(3)
    except:
        print("thread 1 ended")
        ## Insert some clean up functions
        exit
def thread2():
  try:
      while True:
          print("thread2 running")
          sleep(3)
  except:
      ## Insert some cleanup functions
      exit

 t2 = threading.Thread(target = thread1())
 t1 = threading.Thread(target = thread2())

 t1.start()
 t2.start()
```

Comment: Not Pi specific.  This is a general Python question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither thread is actually started.

Instead of

`threading.Thread(target = thread1())`

you should use

`threading.Thread(target = thread1)`

At the moment you are calling a function which never returns so subsequent lines of the script are not executed.